# UGC posts for showing company post from linkedIn for GET method

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I have used postman with this curl request

```
curl -X GET 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts?q=authors&authors=List({urn:li:organization:77ilp7ense0pbf})&sortBy=LAST_MODIFIED' \
-H 'X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer {AQXONiuOuqTCGgEeH3NJBA9b7A8NPbdS5nFjp7nAxUUBnmVmo53UzamJDksan3WSduiUE6u39J9PJNtRVvLhn}'
```

I have added `{urn:li:organization:77ilp7ense0pbf}`, "77ilp7ense0pbf" is my client ID.

I have added `'Authorization: Bearer {AQXONiuOuqTCGgEeH3NJBA9b7A8NPbdS5nFjp7nAxUUBnmVmo53UzamJDksan3WSduiUE6u39J9PJNtRVvLhn}'` as my access token.

But still i am getting this error

```
{
    "serviceErrorCode": 65600,
    "message": "Invalid access token",
    "status": 401
}
```

Is there anything i missed here ? Or any configuration is wrong. Please let me know to get the company posts by UGC posts. I have to get all my linkedIn posts from my company page. https://www.linkedin.com/company/blenheim-chalcot-it-services-india-private-limited/posts/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To get all posts use `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/posts` like [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/posts-api?view=li-lms-2022-08&tabs=http#find-posts-by-authors) and to retrieve some statics about share go [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/share-statistics?view=li-lms-2022-08&tabs=http#retrieve-statistics-for-specific-shares)